# Xcode Bundle identifier issue

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, identifier

I am trying to install 2 apps that i made in Xcode onto a device and have only been able to successfully build one.

on the one that successfully built the bundle identifier was `123456789A.com.company.appnameProject` where "Project" is the project name in grey un-editable text.

for the one that failed the bundle identifier does not have any non-editable text in it and I don't understand why one has un-editable grey text and the other doesn't.

This is the error description `The identity '...' does not match any valiad non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains`

I tried the following bundle identifiers to no success.

```
123456789A.*

123456789A.com.company.appname

123456789A.com.company.appnameProject (project is in editable text)
```

Note: I tried deleting and reinstall provisioning profiles and key-chains.  I would be surprised if anything is wrong with my keychain or provisioning profiles since one app built successfully.

Comment: you may try re creating your private key and re submitting it to apple. Unlike android you can cancel and recreate your signing key without losing previous app installations. If you are developing on another computer and have just installed the provision file you will need the entire developer profile from the machine that was able to deploy. Also you may want to make sure the correct code signing identity is selected in the Build Settings of your app.

Answer (score 1):

the gray text is uneditable because it uses a rfc1034identifier version of your bundle's project name

if you look at the target info you will see bundle identifier looks like this.

```
com.company.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
```

project name is the value next to the icon in the "Targets" section of your Project Property editor.

you can change the name of the target by clicking on the name once while it is already selected. or selecting it and pressing enter.

Changing the name of the target will change the grayed out value in your Bundle identifier.

Sometimes your provision file does not include all of the UDID's that it is supposed to.

You may try making sure they are selected in the itunes connect portal. then downloading a new copy.

You may also try connecting the ios device to xcode and setting it up for development in the "Organizer"

if that does not work. you may want to remove all the provision files from your xcode and from the hard disk where they are stored and re download them from xcode.

Occasionally it is temperamental

Answer (score 0):

Try completing this way your Bundle identifier:

In your organizer/Provisioning profiles you can find the App identifier

12344545.com.name.*

In your Bundle identifier use only after the numbers(dot) and instead (*) your app name, should be this way:

com.name.AppName

This way the The identity '...' does not match any valiad non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains error should be gone, at least it was for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong.  My Code signing identity for the debug phase was for the wrong certificate. It was a pretty simple and embarrassing mistake.

Also thanks to those who answered!